# Ruby namespace mixin methods

Tags: ruby

I have classes namespaced as such:

```
module SocialSearch
  module Scrapers
    class TwitterScraper
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to create a method in `Scrapers` that will be extended within all the classes within the namespace but without manually doing `include Scrapers` in each one of the classes given they are within the `Scrapers` namespace.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no namespaces anywhere in this question, or in Ruby. Modules are not namespaces. The two terms cannot be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SocialSearch::Scrapers.constants.each do
  |k| k = SocialSearch::Scrapers.const_get(k)
  k.extend(SocialSearch::Scrapers)if k.instance_of?(Class)
end
```

or

```
SocialSearch::Scrapers.constants.each do
  |k| k = SocialSearch::Scrapers.const_get(k)
  k.include(SocialSearch::Scrapers)if k.instance_of?(Class)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using inheritance:

```
class Scrapers
  # your common methods for all scrapers
end

class TwitterScraper < Scrapers
  # your twitter-related scraper setup; methods from Scrapers are visible here
end

class FacebookScraper < Scrapers
  # your twitter-related scraper setup; methods from Scrapers are visible here
end
```